# How do I get rid of these errors that Netbeans is reporting on my preprocessed CSS?

Tags: css, netbeans

I use SASS to preprocess my CSS within Netbeans on Ubuntu. If I generate the CSS without minifying, I don't get any errors at all. However, I want to make the CSS minified, so I've added the `--compass --style compressed` options to the SASS command.

When SASS generates a minified `.css` file, Netbeans marks it with all sorts of errors. Mainly they say `Unexpected token RBRACE found`, `Unexpected token NL found`, `Disable filtering of "Unexpected token IMPORTANT_SYM found" CSS parsing error`, and `Premature end of file`.

Despite searching the net, I can't determine if these are errors or warnings that I should take seriously, let alone how to get rid of them. My web pages still seem to render with the right styles, so maybe it's just warnings from Netbeans.

If they're just warnings that don't affect anything, how do I get rid of them? If they are actual errors, why is the SASS preprocessor generating them?

[image: netbeans css errors]

[image: more netbeans css errors]

Comment: Very Helpful and Useful Question and Answer

Answer (score 6):

Starting with NetBeans 7.4 (with all updates), if you click on the bulb icon on line with error, there is option to filter out all css errors in given file/folder/parent folder/project etc. or specific type of error. On your first screenshot, there is such option (not sure why it is missing option to filter all css errors though)

Comment: Thank you for responding. I have tried clicking on those bulb icons, and it seems to change the particular items in the list that displays, but they don't go away entirely, and also on next save they seem to come back.

Comment: I've had the same experience as Questioner, still looking for a better answer.  If I find it, I'll post it.

Comment: Very Helpful and Useful Question and Answer